# after updating to android studio 3.5 ,i am not able to debug the application?

Tags: android-studio

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.margmaker.dnb-hHAt7yiqXvda4ywPos6iBw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.margmaker.dnb-hHAt7yiqXvda4ywPos6iBw==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.margmaker.dnb-hHAt7yiqXvda4ywPos6iBw==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) ((null):-1)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() ((null):-1)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() ((null):-1)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) ((null):-1)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) ((null):-1)
        at void com.margmaker.dnb.activities.DnbLoginRegistration.LoginActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) ((null):-1)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6975)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:240)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:767)